# Инициализация кортежа списком

Tags: python

Я хочу несколько кастомизировать под себя кортеж и столкнулся с некоторым непониманием:

```
class Enum (tuple):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        super(Enum, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __init__(self, *iterable):                                               
        id = 1
        self.vals = {}
        keys = []
        for it in iterable:
            for val in it:
                self.vals[id]=val
                keys.append(id)
                id <<= 1                                                         

        super(Enum, self).__init__(keys)

    def __str__(self):
        return super(Enum, self).__str__()
```

Здесь я переопределил конструктор и инициализирую базовый списком ключей keys, который из себя представляет список чисел как то: `[1,2,4,...]`

Теперь проверяем:

```
def main():
    e = Enum(['first','dfdf','rt'])
    print e[0]
    print type(e)
    print e
```

Соответственно, в `e[0]` я ожидаю увидеть 1, но получаю None. А в `print e` ожидаю увидеть `(1,2,4)`, но получаю на выходе `('first', 'dfdf', 'rt')` - я не понимаю, почему базовый tuple инициализировался списком слов, а не списком ключей keys, ведь я переопределял его инициализацию: `super(Enum, self).__init__(keys)`

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Можете в общих словах описать функционал, который реализует ваша модифицированная структура данных?

Comment: @mkkik, что-то наподобие Enum-а из 3-его питона, но с возможностью сочетания ключей (флагов) путем побитового сложения подобно .NET enum-у.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple.__init__` ничего не делает и аргументы игнорирует, встроенные объекты обычно формируются еще на этапе `__new__` и дальше уже не меняются (по крайней мере иммутабельные, как `tuple`).

```py
class MyTuple(tuple):
  def __new__(cls, *it):
    return tuple.__new__(cls, it)

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'MyTuple({})'.format(', '.join(map(str, self)))

print(MyTuple(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Красота! Заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я не туда смотрю, но в Python уже есть модуль `enum`, который реализует перечисления,что вам и нужно.

Comment: в 3 - есть, в 2- нет